# grub boot menu is not showing after BIOS update

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, 22.04, windows-11

I updated my BIOS and it told me to restart the PC for it to work, but after restarting I noticed that the dual boot menu isn't showing anymore. I have both the Windows 11 and Ubuntu 22.04 on the same disk, but on different partitions.

I have tried almost everything, but nothing is working.

[image: Disk Management Image]

Comment: For Linux repairs better to show from gparted. Windows does not correctly see Linux partitions. Is the 150GB #5 your Ubuntu install? Bitlocker on also prevents Linux tools from correctly seeing Windows partitions. Does your one time boot key show an Ubuntu entry? Or with bitlocker off, does it then show ubuntu entry? Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version with your USB installer or any working install over somewhat older ISO. 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score -1):

I also have this problem with my MSI board,
you have to manually re-install Grub2 with a Live Image from your USB or DVD, cause the BIOS update clears the nvram of motherboard.

Here a list of steps you have to do:

- Boot Ubuntu from Live CD or USB
- Mount your partitions to /mnt like:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdaX /mnt #This should be your root partition, according to your screenshot you don't have more partitions as root(/) and EFI

sudo mount /dev/sdaY(EFI Partition, where Ubuntu installed GRUB) /mnt/boot/efi
```

- Prepare and start chroot with:

```
sudo mount -o bind /dev /mnt/dev 
sudo mount -o bind /sys /mnt/sys 
sudo mount -t proc /proc /mnt/proc 
sudo cp /proc/mounts /mnt/etc/mtab 
sudo chroot /mnt /bin/bash
```

- Then re-install and renew GRUB with:

```
grub-install
update-grub
```

- Reboot and you are finish